# Multi language customer portals

Tags: apex

We have a customer portal in English, we are trying to use the same portal for different language based on the customers language,when the customer logs in, based on his language the text should be displayed in his language, how can we acheive this functionality with the same custom code that we have currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [Translation workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wbench.htm) for your org and use [custom labels](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_edit.htm&language=en_US) on all visualforce pages .

Apart from this you will use language attribute on the apex:page

```
<apex:page language="{!yourlanguage}"/>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_label.htm